# How to define in JS when AngularJS finished compiling his view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to call some JQ plugin for elements defined in AngularJS View template, so when I will call, for example

```
   $(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
});
```

It will not working because `id="selectable"` will be visible after AngularJS finished its compiling. Insert this code inside controller wrong idea (did it).

Comment: You are right, you can't use `$( "#selectable" ).selectable();` reliably in Angular app. And you should not. Create a directive for this.

Comment: I am using components.So can't do this.

Comment: You are already using directives - components are just special case of directives. So not only you can, but you **should** do it this way. This type of functionality must be a directive. What you should never do is what you are trying with the code you posted.

Comment: I know, about rules, but if I need have connection with this plugin.It's really complex do something with AngularJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a directive

```
angular.module('module').directive('my-selectable', function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).selectable();
        }
    }
});
```

and in your view

```
<select my-selectable>
...
</select>
```

I haven't tested but should work

I recommend the directive but if you want to detect when view is loaded if you are using ui-router

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    $('selector').selectable();
});
```

Just have in mind that this code will loaded every time the state has change

Comment: `element` instead of `$(element)` should be enough as `element` is a jquery instance already. angular.js uses jQuery Lite and if the full version is loaded it will use that instead so the plugin should be available.

Comment: I don't use directive because I use components in angularJS/

Comment: Directive is component, why do you call them component ? you use angular 2 ? 
In that case create and angular2 components that do the same stuff than this example...

Comment: Post more code in your first question 
The directive code, the html that call this directive.

Comment: stalin - Thanks! Directive - works ! But is it OK  using this approach ?

Comment: Arnaud Gueras - all ok! Thanks!

Comment: @VladyslavHavrylenko the best way to add a jquery plugin or dom modification is to use a directive

Comment: Have new problem.  Inside $(element).selectable(--here--) Do some function and call Service which should  delivery some data to another controller, but it doesn't work - in another controller I don't get any results from service!

Answer (score 1):

Always remember that in Angular Compile phase DOM creation happens so anything which is related to events linking or DOM manipulation will not work in this phase.
This is the reason Angular has provided link phase where you can do the above operations. 
Second thing, in link phase you always get the element instance so no need to use $ in this block. You can always directly use it.

### Possibly solution would be:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
     ...,
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.selectable();
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: Have new problem. Inside $(element).selectable(--here--) Do some function and call Service which should delivery some data to another controller, but it doesn't work - in another controller I don't get any results from Service!